# Ether backed tokens

Tags: tokens

I am playing around with the advanced token functions over at the [Ethereum Token tutorial](https://www.ethereum.org/token#full-coin-code).

The contract is deploying fine on the testnet, balances my account with the created tokens and I can set the buy and sell price but now what? I can't buy tokens from the Token contract and neither can I send Ether or Tokens to it...

Am I missing something? I have not changed any of the sample code.

Comment: Can you provide some details on what you are doing exactly, some log or all the command lines you typed ?

Comment: I am doing it all in Mist. All I am doing is copy & paste the code from the Ethereum page I linked above and deploy the contract in Mist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. msg.value has to be set in wei - I was setting it in Ether.

Comment: Can only do that tomorrow.